# Do Decorators in Python necessarily implement the Decorator Pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

In Python,

1. Is it correct that  decorators in Python can change the interface of
   the decorated function/class, e.g. change the signature of the
   decorated functions and methods of decorated class? For example:

   ```
   >>> def MyDecorator(func):
   ...     def NewFunc():
   ...         pass
   ...     return NewFunc
   ... 
   >>> @MyDecorator
   ... def MyFunc(a, b, c):
   ...     print(a,b,c)
   ...
   ```
2. So decorators in Python are not necessarily used for implementing the decorator design pattern as described in the book "Design Pattern" by GoF?
3. Is it a bad practice to write a decorator which change the interface of the decorated function/class?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the question is good - but too broad. I mean you have 3 question (even if they are loosely connected) instead of just one. Could you try to narrow the scope of the question?

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks. The questions to me are closely related, and they are actually the same question stated in different forms. If I split them into three posts, they will be duplicates, I am afraid.

Answer (score 2):

From [python.org](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DecoratorPattern) (my emphasis):

> The DecoratorPattern is a pattern described in the DesignPatternsBook.
>   It is a way of apparently modifying an object's behavior, by enclosing
>   it inside a decorating object with a similar interface.
>
> **This is not to be confused with PythonDecorators**, which is a language
>   feature for dynamically modifying a function or class.

So I guess the answers to your questions are:

1. Yes
2. That's correct
3. No

Comment: Thanks. What are some good uses of decorators in Python that change interface of decorated function/class?

Comment: An example from the top of my head: Say you have a function that returns an object of type A. Then you realize that while this works on Linux, the object A is unsuitable for Windows, and it would be better to use object of type B instead when running on Windows. So you write a decorator that checks the current OS. If it's Windows, it modifies the returned value to be of type B instead of A.

Answer (score 2):

You can also find some answers in the well-known Python [decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) library documentation.

Quoting the [Introduction](http://decorator.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests.documentation.html#definitions):

> Technically speaking, any Python object which can be called with one argument can be used as a decorator. However, this definition is somewhat too large to be really useful. It is more convenient to split the generic class of decorators in two subclasses:
>
> **signature-preserving decorators:**
>
> Callable objects which accept a function as input and return a function as output, with the same signature.
>
> **signature-changing decorators:**
>
> Decorators which change the signature of their input function, or decorators that return non-callable objects.
>
> **Signature-changing decorators** have their use: for instance, the builtin classes staticmethod and classmethod are in this group. They take functions and return descriptor objects which are neither functions, nor callables.
>
> Still, **signature-preserving decorators** are more common, and easier to reason about. In particular, they can be composed together, whereas other decorators generally cannot.

Same answers:

1. Yes
2. That's correct
3. No